# Create an element with namespace dependent on input XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

As part of an XSLT 1.0 transformation, I need to match an element whose `local-name()` is (say) `fred`.  Obviously in this case there might be a namespace in effect or there might not be.

Within that match, I need to create an element whose local name should be `location`.

Is `<xsl:element>` sufficient for this purpose?  Should I explicitly set its `namespace` attribute?  Is there another way to create an element whose namespace is set appropriately, if there is one, and omitted if there is not?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `<xsl:element>` controls the output, it has nothing to do with matching the input. Is there a difference in the required output if the matched node is in a namespace or if it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `*[local-name() = 'fred']` to match an element with a local name of "fred" regardless of its namespace.

> Within that match, I need to create an element whose local name should
>   be `location`.

Here, your question becomes a bit unclear.  The namespace (or lack of namespace) of an element you create in an output document is up to you; it needn't have any tie to the input document.  If it should in some way be tied to a namespace found in the input document, you have to say from which part of the input document the namespace should come.

**Update per OP comment below:**

> I want to use the namespace of parent fred element, whatever it may
>   be, or if it is null/empty.

Ah, ok, this example may help then.  Given this XML input document

```
<root xmlns="http://www.example.com">
  <fred/>
</root>
```

the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*[local-name() = 'root']/*[local-name() = 'fred']">
    <xsl:element name="location"
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <location xmlns="http://www.example.com"/>
```

which uses the namespace of the `fred` element from the input XML.

And when given this XML input document

```
<root>
  <fred/>
</root>
```

will produce this output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <location/>
```

where `location` is in no namespace.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use the namespace of parent `fred` element, whatever it may be, or if it is `null`/empty. Does that help? It is sounding like I should be referring to a variable that is computed from the parent element's namespace, possibly with some conditional around it to handle the case where there is no parent element namespace. Am I on the right track?